# fancyhdr: Title don't match title number

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

Some of my titles in the header don't match the number. This happens in page 3 in the example. What can be a solution or a work around?

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{ #1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{ #1}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{ #1}}

\rfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\thesubsection \rightmark}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand {\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand {\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\begin{document}


\chapter{Some chapter}

\section{Section I}
\lipsum[1]

\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Section II}

\lipsum[1-2]

\subsection{Subsection One}
\lipsum[1-2]

\subsection{Subsection Two}
\lipsum[1-2]



\section{Section III}
\lipsum[1-2]

\subsection{Subsection for this section}
\lipsum[1-2]

\subsection{Another subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess that you have problem with the number based on your redefinition of the marks.

Comment: Exactly what information do you want to show in the headers for your document?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is the 1st or last chapter/section/subsection mentioned on a page. It only has to correspond to the chapter/section/subsection number.
For instance on Page 3: It doesn't matter if in the header is "1.2.2 Subsection Two" or "1.3.0 Section III"

Answer (score 2):

The section number must be added along with the title in `\markright`. Doing it in the header is too late.

The numbering is controlled by counter `secnumdepth`. Therefore the example also checks
for the value of `secnumdepth` to avoid the case that a number is given in the header, but not in the text.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{%
  \markright{%
    \ifnum\value{secnumdepth}>1 %
      \thesubsection~%
    \fi
    #1%
  }%
}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  \markright{%
    \ifnum\value{secnumdepth}>0 %
      \thesection~%
    \fi
    #1%
  }%
}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markright{%
    \ifnum\value{secnumdepth}>-1 %
      \thechapter~%
    \fi
    #1%
  }%
}

\rfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand {\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand {\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Some chapter}

\section{Section I}
\lipsum[1]

\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Section II}

\lipsum[1-2]

\subsection{Subsection One}
\lipsum[1-2]

\subsection{Subsection Two}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Section III}
\lipsum[1-2]

\subsection{Subsection for this section}
\lipsum[1-2]

\subsection{Another subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```